# Passing Attributes of a Auto-Implemented Property to its field

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, field

I have the following Problem: I would like to add an attribute to an auto-implemented property `prop` of a class `Foo` in the first step.
In a second step I'm iterating over all fields of `Foo` and I copy values to these fields (values of fields of auto-implemented Properties are also found and copied). In this part I need access to the information of the Attribute.

```
class FieldSetter
{
    // This Method is called from outside and should work for any class
    private void SetFieldValues(object unknownObject)
    {
        foreach (var field in
                unknownObject.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance |
                                       BindingFlags.Static).Where((field) => !field.IsLiteral))
        {
            if (!EvalAttribute(Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(field))) // the Attribute should be accessed here
            {
                // Do something if no special Information is set
                field.SetValue(a, "default Value");
            }

            else
            {
                // Do special things
                field.SetValue(a, "special Value");
            }
        }

    }


    internal static bool EvalAttribute(Attribute[] attributes)
    {

        foreach (System.Attribute attr in attributes)
        {
            var myAttr = attr as MyAttribute;
            if (myAttr != null)
            {
                if (myAttr.SomeAttributeValues == "Specific Attribute Value")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

// This class is a example for how a given Object can look like
class Foo
{
    [MyAttribute("Example Information")] // This Attribute won't be accessed via prop-Field
    int prop { get; set; }

    [MyAttribute("Another Example Information")] // This Attribute won't be accessed via prop-Field
    int field;

    //... lots of other fields and properties
}


[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(string someInformation)
    {
        SomeAttributeValues = someInformation;
    }

    public string SomeAttributeValues;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to iterate over all of the *fields* instead of iterating over the *properties*? What would you do if `prop` wasn't an auto-property, but had some other special implementation? There is a hacky way to accomplish what you're doing, but I'd suggest you explore the possibility of accessing property setters directly first.

Comment: I don't know the classes, which are processed by `SetFieldValues`. So Foo is a "Black Box" for me. Another Way may be, to except fields that have properties from my iteration. The main reason i'd like to to this is: I have 2 similar objects. Each object contains different informations (private or public primitive Fields, ..., fields with classes (they will also be copied recursively), ... , fields from Auto-Properties, ... ). And i want to Merged all those informations in 1 instance.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make it clear which information you have access to and which you don't. Is your code given an assembly? A list of types? A list of fields? A list of attributes? If your code is saying `GetFields()`, then it could just as easily say `GetProperties()`, right?

Comment: Youre right, I can additionaly use `GetProperties()`, but then i have to exclude the corresponding fields from my `GetFields()` iteration as well. Otherwise some fields will be processed with AND without the attribute Information.

Comment: And you're positive you want to access *private* fields? It seems like a really odd requirement to be able to detect a custom attribute on a private member. Can you not get away with only accessing public fields and properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.  If you need to have the attribute on the field, you need to declare the field yourself and not use auto-properties.  Alternately, you can reflect over the properties which will have the attribute when you look for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the properties you're interested in will always be auto-implemented, and you have some idea of what compiler will be used to compile the types you're interested in, you could leverage the fact that the backing fields for auto-generated properties follow a specific naming convention. For example, the code you've provided ends up with a field name like this:

```
<prop>k__BackingField
```

This is a distinctive name, which cannot be produced directly by C# code, so if you run into a field with a name like this you could parse out the property name from between the angle brackets, and use `GetProperty()` on that name.

However, this is a hacky solution because:

1. The name used for backing fields is an implementation detail, which could theoretically change in future versions of .NET, or for alternative compilers like Mono.
2. There's nothing to ensure that the fields you find will always be tied to auto-properties. What would your expectations be if you ran into this?

   ```
   class Foo
   {
       int field;

       [MyAttribute("Example Information")]
       int prop { get{return field;} set {return field;} }

       //... lots of other fields and properties
   }
   ```

I'd strongly suggest that you spend more time analyzing what your real business need and constraints are, and see if there's not another, more robust way to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think in my case it will be enough, if I apply the Attribute to the CustomType of a field or a property. This will resolve my problem so far.

Comment: Just for your imagination: Lets say I want to merge informations of two objects `Foo1` and `Foo2`, which implement an interface `IFoo`, which has several List-Properties. Some List-Properties allow duplicated entries, others don't. How can I differ between those merging-behaviors without knowing these Lists explicit?

Comment: @MarkusWeber: Do those properties on `IFoo` have public getters and setters? Are all the values you're interested in on `IFoo`, or are there other fields that you're trying to gather information for which aren't related to an interface? If the latter... why? What guarantee do you have that the `IFoo` properties are implemented implicitly by an auto-property, and not explicitly or by a custom property implementation?